# Is it possible to add iPad parameter "deviceOrientation" in testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs?

Tags: testing, ipad, testcafe, device-orientation, saucelabs

My team follows this example for our browser configuration on Saucelabs:
https://github.com/saucelabs/testcafe-browser-provider-ios

To be exact, this is what we have in our code:
`"test-ipad": "testcafe 'saucelabs:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) Simulator@13.3' ourService.js --speed 0.5"`

But now we are facing a problem that we need to run the iPad in the vertical orientation.
Saucelabs says this can be configured:
https://support.saucelabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/225105867-Running-Mobile-Tests-in-Both-Landscape-and-Portrait-Mode
But I cannot find it anything I can read about testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs.

Anyone knows how to add the device orientation parameter in that line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the [SAUCE_CAPABILITIES_OVERRIDES_PATH](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs#configuration) option to specify the path to the file that contains overrides for capabilities. In that file, you can set the desired configuration. See [SauceLabs Test Configuration](https://docs.saucelabs.com/dev/test-configuration-options/index.html) for details.